# Cant attach to ephemeral container

Tags: kubernetes

I created ephemeral container and tried to attach it, but in pod status unable to find anything about it, seems spec are updated with empty containerID. How to fix it? (ephemral containers are work fine on another cluster with same version and cluster configs are same as per theory)

k8s version: v1.20 (ephemeral container are enabled in api, kube-scheduler, etcd, kubelet, kube-controller-manager).
Also now i can`t update cluster to last release.

I used this manual to create ephemeral container https://iximiuz.com/en/posts/kubernetes-ephemeral-containers/

```
kubectl get pods slim-c5f4b9767-47ldt -n test-ephemeral-cont -o jsonpath={'.spec.ephemeralContainers'} | jq
[
  {
    "image": "busybox",
    "imagePullPolicy": "Always",
    "name": "debugger-4hl96",
    "resources": {},
    "stdin": true,
    "targetContainerName": "app",
    "terminationMessagePath": "/dev/termination-log",
    "terminationMessagePolicy": "File",
    "tty": true
  }
]
```

Status result is as below

```
kubectl get pods slim-c5f4b9767-47ldt -n test-ephemeral-cont -o jsonpath={'.spec.ephemeralContainerStatuses'} | jq
```

I tried to create container with this article, and container should start fine.